# Tkinter : Syntax highlighting for Text widget

Tags: python, text, syntax, tkinter

Can anyone explain how to add syntax highlighting to a Tkinter `Text` widget ?

Every time the program finds a matching word, it would color that word to how I want. Such as : Color the word `tkinter` in pink and `in` in blue. But when I type in `Tkinter`, it color `Tk--ter` in yellow and `in` in blue.

How can I fix this ? Thanks !

Comment: You may want to look at [Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/). It would be a lot easier than rolling your own. If you still want to try to fix your version you may want to describe how you are finding keywords to highlight (i.e. what is your regular expression).

Answer (score 6):

This is an extension of [tfpf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68671928/10292330).

When you call `ic.make_pat()` it returns the entire regular expression for python formatting. Whereas it may seem convenient to `OR` in some extra expressions, to one side or the other, it doesn't really give you much control, and it becomes cumbersome quickly. A potentially more useful and definitely more customizable approach would be to print/copy/paste `ic.make_pat()`, and break it up similar to below. This also has the bonus side-effect that you don't have to worry about how to call `ic.make_pat()` in regards to python versions because, after you do this you aren't going to use `ic.make_pat()`, at all.

```py
#syntax highlighter patterns
KEYWORD   = r"\b(?P<KEYWORD>False|None|True|and|as|assert|async|await|break|class|continue|def|del|elif|else|except|finally|for|from|global|if|import|in|is|lambda|nonlocal|not|or|pass|raise|return|try|while|with|yield)\b"
EXCEPTION = r"([^.'\"\\#]\b|^)(?P<EXCEPTION>ArithmeticError|AssertionError|AttributeError|BaseException|BlockingIOError|BrokenPipeError|BufferError|BytesWarning|ChildProcessError|ConnectionAbortedError|ConnectionError|ConnectionRefusedError|ConnectionResetError|DeprecationWarning|EOFError|Ellipsis|EnvironmentError|Exception|FileExistsError|FileNotFoundError|FloatingPointError|FutureWarning|GeneratorExit|IOError|ImportError|ImportWarning|IndentationError|IndexError|InterruptedError|IsADirectoryError|KeyError|KeyboardInterrupt|LookupError|MemoryError|ModuleNotFoundError|NameError|NotADirectoryError|NotImplemented|NotImplementedError|OSError|OverflowError|PendingDeprecationWarning|PermissionError|ProcessLookupError|RecursionError|ReferenceError|ResourceWarning|RuntimeError|RuntimeWarning|StopAsyncIteration|StopIteration|SyntaxError|SyntaxWarning|SystemError|SystemExit|TabError|TimeoutError|TypeError|UnboundLocalError|UnicodeDecodeError|UnicodeEncodeError|UnicodeError|UnicodeTranslateError|UnicodeWarning|UserWarning|ValueError|Warning|WindowsError|ZeroDivisionError)\b"
BUILTIN   = r"([^.'\"\\#]\b|^)(?P<BUILTIN>abs|all|any|ascii|bin|breakpoint|callable|chr|classmethod|compile|complex|copyright|credits|delattr|dir|divmod|enumerate|eval|exec|exit|filter|format|frozenset|getattr|globals|hasattr|hash|help|hex|id|input|isinstance|issubclass|iter|len|license|locals|map|max|memoryview|min|next|oct|open|ord|pow|print|quit|range|repr|reversed|round|set|setattr|slice|sorted|staticmethod|sum|type|vars|zip)\b"
DOCSTRING = r"(?P<DOCSTRING>(?i:r|u|f|fr|rf|b|br|rb)?'''[^'\\]*((\\.|'(?!''))[^'\\]*)*(''')?|(?i:r|u|f|fr|rf|b|br|rb)?\"\"\"[^\"\\]*((\\.|\"(?!\"\"))[^\"\\]*)*(\"\"\")?)"
STRING    = r"(?P<STRING>(?i:r|u|f|fr|rf|b|br|rb)?'[^'\\\n]*(\\.[^'\\\n]*)*'?|(?i:r|u|f|fr|rf|b|br|rb)?\"[^\"\\\n]*(\\.[^\"\\\n]*)*\"?)"
TYPES     = r"\b(?P<TYPES>bool|bytearray|bytes|dict|float|int|list|str|tuple|object)\b"
NUMBER    = r"\b(?P<NUMBER>((0x|0b|0o|#)[\da-fA-F]+)|((\d*\.)?\d+))\b"
CLASSDEF  = r"(?<=\bclass)[ \t]+(?P<CLASSDEF>\w+)[ \t]*[:\(]" #recolor of DEFINITION for class definitions
DECORATOR = r"(^[ \t]*(?P<DECORATOR>@[\w\d\.]+))"
INSTANCE  = r"\b(?P<INSTANCE>super|self|cls)\b"
COMMENT   = r"(?P<COMMENT>#[^\n]*)"
SYNC      = r"(?P<SYNC>\n)"
```

Then you can concat all of those patterns, in whatever order suits you, as below:

```
PROG   = rf"{KEYWORD}|{BUILTIN}|{EXCEPTION}|{TYPES}|{COMMENT}|{DOCSTRING}|{STRING}|{SYNC}|{INSTANCE}|{DECORATOR}|{NUMBER}|{CLASSDEF}"
```

You may notice that `DEFINITION` is not present in any of the above patterns. That's because the above patterns are for `.prog`, but the `DEFINITION` pattern is determined by `.idprog`. Below is mine. I wanted class definitions to be a different color so, my pattern ignores definitions that are preceded with `class`. If you don't intend to make some exceptions to `DEFINITION` you don't have to mess with it, at all.

```
#original - r"\s+(\w+)"
IDPROG = r"(?<!class)\s+(\w+)"
```

The next thing to consider is `tagdefs`. Instead of line by line adding/modifying a key, you can just predefine `tagdefs`. Below is an example. Note that every `regex group` name used in the first set of patterns above, is represented with a key in the below object. Also note that `DEFINITION` is  included here. Each object below becomes `options` for `tag_configure`, and you can use any `option` that `tag_configure` accepts. Colors and fonts are my own, and including them is unnecessary to the example.

```
TAGDEFS   = {   'COMMENT'    : {'foreground': CHARBLUE  , 'background': None},
                'TYPES'      : {'foreground': CLOUD2    , 'background': None},
                'NUMBER'     : {'foreground': LEMON     , 'background': None},
                'BUILTIN'    : {'foreground': OVERCAST  , 'background': None},
                'STRING'     : {'foreground': PUMPKIN   , 'background': None},
                'DOCSTRING'  : {'foreground': STORMY    , 'background': None},
                'EXCEPTION'  : {'foreground': CLOUD2    , 'background': None, 'font':FONTBOLD},
                'DEFINITION' : {'foreground': SAILOR    , 'background': None, 'font':FONTBOLD},
                'DECORATOR'  : {'foreground': CLOUD2    , 'background': None, 'font':FONTITAL},
                'INSTANCE'   : {'foreground': CLOUD     , 'background': None, 'font':FONTITAL},
                'KEYWORD'    : {'foreground': DK_SEAFOAM, 'background': None, 'font':FONTBOLD},
                'CLASSDEF'   : {'foreground': PURPLE    , 'background': None, 'font':FONTBOLD},
            }

'''
#what literally happens to this data when it is applied
for tag, cfg in self.tagdefs.items():
    self.tag_configure(tag, **cfg)
'''
```

Once you have that setup you can easily plug everything in. If you make a custom text widget you could put the below in `__init__` and change `YourTextWidget` to `self`. Otherwise, just change `YourTextWidget` to the instance name of the text widget you want to connect this to (as it is in [tfpf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68671928/10292330)).

```
cd         = ic.ColorDelegator()
cd.prog    = re.compile(PROG, re.S|re.M)
cd.idprog  = re.compile(IDPROG, re.S)
cd.tagdefs = {**cd.tagdefs, **TAGDEFS}
ip.Percolator(YourTextWidget).insertfilter(cd)
```

---

`cd.tagdefs = {**cd.tagdefs, **TAGDEFS}`

Why did I do it this way? We don't omit any values with this method. What if `KEYWORD` was defined in `tagdefs`, but not in `TAGDEFS`? If we didn't first unpack `tagdefs` into itself we would lose `KEYWORD`.

To sum up this end of the system: one big regex is run, and whatever `regex group` name matches becomes the name of the tag to apply. Whatever new `regex groups` you create should (maybe must) have an identically named key in `.tagdefs`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a follow-up to [igwd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67775442). `idlelib.colorizer.ColorDelegator` and `idlelib.percolator.Percolator` don't seem to be documented well, so I decided to post what I found.

If you're looking to highlight words like 'tkinter' and 'in', you probably want normal Python syntax highlighting and a few additions.

```
import idlelib.colorizer as ic
import idlelib.percolator as ip
import re
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Python Syntax Highlighting')

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

cdg = ic.ColorDelegator()
cdg.prog = re.compile(r'\b(?P<MYGROUP>tkinter)\b|' + ic.make_pat(), re.S)
cdg.idprog = re.compile(r'\s+(\w+)', re.S)

cdg.tagdefs['MYGROUP'] = {'foreground': '#7F7F7F', 'background': '#FFFFFF'}

# These five lines are optional. If omitted, default colours are used.
cdg.tagdefs['COMMENT'] = {'foreground': '#FF0000', 'background': '#FFFFFF'}
cdg.tagdefs['KEYWORD'] = {'foreground': '#007F00', 'background': '#FFFFFF'}
cdg.tagdefs['BUILTIN'] = {'foreground': '#7F7F00', 'background': '#FFFFFF'}
cdg.tagdefs['STRING'] = {'foreground': '#7F3F00', 'background': '#FFFFFF'}
cdg.tagdefs['DEFINITION'] = {'foreground': '#007F7F', 'background': '#FFFFFF'}

ip.Percolator(text).insertfilter(cdg)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Example Output]

The above MWE works with Python 3.8. On Python 3.10, just replace `cdg.prog = re.compile(r'\b(?P<MYGROUP>tkinter)\b|' + ic.make_pat(), re.S)` with `cdg.prog = re.compile(r'\b(?P<MYGROUP>tkinter)\b|' + ic.make_pat().pattern, re.S)`. I have not tested this with other Python versions.

Answer (score 2):

These codes can achieve syntax highlighting in IDLE.
You can copy the source code and modify certain things.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from idlelib.percolator import Percolator
from idlelib.colorizer import ColorDelegator
main = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(main)
text.pack()
Percolator(text).insertfilter(ColorDelegator())
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you have IDLE installed, this is the best solution. You can customise the colours, too! `cdg = ColorDelegator(); cdg.tagdefs['COMMENT'] = {'foreground': '#007FFF', 'background': '#333333'}; Percolator(text).insertfilter(cdg)`

Comment: @tfpf this is a good solution for Windows, probably. On Mac it's slow, and the syntax isn't highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `tag` to do this. You can configure the tag to have certain backgrounds, fonts, text sizes, colors etc. And then add these tags to the text you want to configure.

All of this is in the [documentation](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/text.htm).

Comment: The documentation link does not work (anymore?). Any hints about a working link for the documentation?

Comment: https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/text.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use [tags](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-tag.html). I am  going to implement the notions given there.

**Example:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Begueradj")
text = tk.Text(root)
# Insert some text
text.insert(tk.INSERT, "Security ")
text.insert(tk.END, " Pentesting ")
text.insert(tk.END, "Hacking ")
text.insert(tk.END, "Coding")
text.pack()
# Create some tags
text.tag_add("one", "1.0", "1.8")
text.tag_add("two", "1.10", "1.20")
text.tag_add("three", "1.21", "1.28")
text.tag_add("four", "1.29", "1.36")
#Configure the tags
text.tag_config("one", background="yellow", foreground="blue")
text.tag_config("two", background="black", foreground="green")
text.tag_config("three", background="blue", foreground="yellow")
text.tag_config("four", background="red", foreground="black")
#Start the program
root.mainloop()
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: But sometimes I type in "print"(which contains the word "int" in it), it highlights "int" in blue and the rest in yellow

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786590/tkinter-pygments-strange-results-in-highlighting/50820118#50820118)
- [pygments](https://pygments.org/docs/) example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65192363/markdown-text-highlighting-performance-issues-tkinter/65200005#65200005) where is using get_style_by_name("default").list_styles() for built-in styles; replace lexer with PythonLexer for Python
- [fancycompleter](https://github.com/pdbpp/fancycompleter)
- [idlelib](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/idlelib) example:

  ```
  from tkinter import Tk
  from tkinter import Text
  from idlelib.colorizer import ColorDelegator, color_config
  from idlelib.percolator import Percolator
  from idlelib.undo import UndoDelegator


  class CustomEditor:
      def __init__(self):
          self.root = Tk()
          self.text = text = Text(self.root)
          text.pack()

          self.perc = perc = Percolator(text)
          self.undo = undo = UndoDelegator()
          perc.insertfilter(undo)
          self.color = None
          self.code_context = None
          self.ResetColorizer()

      def _add_colorizer(self):
          if self.color:
              return
          self.color = ColorDelegator()
          self.perc.insertfilterafter(filter=self.color, after=self.undo)

      def _rm_colorizer(self):
          if not self.color:
              return
          self.color.removecolors()
          self.perc.removefilter(self.color)
          self.color = None

      def ResetColorizer(self):
          self._rm_colorizer()
          self._add_colorizer()
          color_config(self.text)


  editor = CustomEditor()
  editor.text.insert(1.0, "print('Hello')\n")
  editor.text.focus_set()
  editor.root.mainloop()
  ```