# highlighting selected words in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to highlight the words which are present in a file . I have stored the file in a var called `KEYWORDS` with the arguments as `open("word-lists/keywords").read().split("\n")`

this is the code which handles the highlighting(from another stack overflow anwser):

```
    print("pressed")
    index = text.search(r'\s', "insert", backwards=True, regexp=True)
    if index == "":
        index = "1.0"
    else:
        index = text.index("%s+1c" % index)
    word = text.get(index, "insert")
    if word in KEYWORDS:
        text.tag_add("highlight", index, "%s+%dc" % (index, len(word)))
    else:
        text.tag_remove("highlight", index, "%s+%dc" % (index, len(word)))
```

and I use this to call this function :
`text.bind("<Key>", Syntaxhighlight)`

the words are being highlighted only if i press the spacebar before typing .
i want that it should start from the start.

heres the full code:

```
win = tkinter.Tk()
text = tkinter.Text(win, font=font, bg=BACKGROUND, fg=FOREGROUND, insertbackground=FOREGROUND, borderwidth=0,
                    highlightthickness=0)
text.pack(expand=True, side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
text.tag_configure("highlight", foreground=KEYWORD, underline=False)


def Syntaxhighlight(event):
    print("pressed")
    index = text.search(r'\s', "insert", backwards=True, regexp=True)
    if index == "":
        index = "1.0"
    else:
        index = text.index("%s+1c" % index)
    word = text.get(index, "insert")
    if word in KEYWORDS:
        text.tag_add("highlight", index, "%s+%dc" % (index, len(word)))
    else:
        text.tag_remove("highlight", index, "%s+%dc" % (index, len(word)))

text.bind("<Key>", Syntaxhighlight)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve], preferably one that doesn't require the data file. You can hard-code a list of a couple of works.

Comment: yaa sorry for that will do it

Comment: If you want it to highlight before you type, have you tried just calling `Syntaxhighlight` at the start of the program?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467574/proper-syntax-highlighting-in-text-tkinter check this. Not exactly a text file but it does syntax highlighting. I had asked the question. Copy that. Also, provide the path where python.yaml was stored on your computer

Comment: @BryanOakley yes i have tried that , but did not work

Comment: Do you mean that the *first* word cannot be highlighted even it is within the keyword list?  But adding a space before it can?

Comment: yes i meant that

Comment: @acw1668 yes i meant that